# How can Gradle build an Rpm containing the outputs of some subprojects?

Tags: java, gradle, rpm

I've got a multi-project setup, where I'd like to build Rpm files from certain subprojects, containing artefacts from other subprojects. Seems like I need help with some Gradle basics.

The project layout is like the below:

```
rootProject
|
|-commonLibs
|
|---serviceA
| |
| |--module1
| \--module2
|
\---serviceB
  |
  |--module3
  \--module4
```

Both services depend on commonLibs.

I'm using [nebula.os-package](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin) 2.0.2 and a Gradle 2.2 snapshot release.

Since services A and B will run on different machines, of course I want them in different RPM.

What I'd like to accomplish is to have each of the Rpms include:

1. the outputs (jars) of commonLibs (or perhaps all dependency jars, even)
2. certain artifacts (jars and resource files) of the submodules

I prefer to avoid listing each file to include, because I'll be adding more submodules later. And we could surely take advantage of Gradle's build-by-convention mechanics here.

So, I was thinking I'd do something like this in the `build.gradle` of serviceA and serviceB:

```
apply plugin: 'os-package'
ospackage {
   ext.outputFiles = []
   project.childProjects.each {
     jar.outputs.files.each { File f ->
        outputs.add (f)
     }
   }
   from files(outputFiles) {
     into '/opt/mybusiness/product/lib'
   }
}
```

Clearly, this doesn't work:

```
gradlew serviceA:buildRpm
[...]
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':serviceA'.
> Could not find property 'jar' on com.netflix.gradle.plugins.packaging.ProjectPackagingExtension_Decorated@2805c769.
```

OK, serviceA is not a Java project, so I didn't apply the java plugin to it, only the os-package plugin. The submodules, however, are both applying the 'java' plugin, so I was assuming that I could access their jar tasks from the `each` closure. This must be a build order problem. Right?

What should I be doing instead, in my position? Any examples of strategies for multi-project builds using nebula.os-package are welcome. I've been searching the web, but I'm having problems finding anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, something like this should do the trick - to be added in build.gradle of :serviceA & :serviceB

```
configurations {
    commonJars
}

dependencies {
    commonJars project( path: ':commonLibs' ) // might be needed to add 'configuration' as well
}

ospackage {
    from configurations.commonJars
    ..
}
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I can't find a `collect()` method on the ConfigurationContainer class, and neither can Gradle:
`> Could not find method collect() for arguments [build_cxsc6r4a708h9nwfqzteojnjd$_run_closure2_closure5@3a6887f7, build_cxsc6r4a708h9nwfqzteojnjd$_run_closure2_
closure6@5a355bd4] on configuration ':serviceA:commonJars'.`

Comment: We're having this kind of setups (albeit with zip/tar task) running on gradle 2.1, 1.11, and that's working fine.. not sure about the ospackage, would expect same behavior (given their documentation)

Comment: giving it another look, and in fact you can leave out the ".collect {it}", since it has no added value.. (collect method on groovy collections). btw: the collect method is not looked for in the ConfigurationContainer class, yet in the Container class...

Comment: Yes, indeed, that makes it build succesfully, and does exactly what it should (ie includes the commonLibs jars). Edited your answer to reflect the correct syntax.

Comment: What's more, this solution also includes in my RPM all the dependencies of :commonLibs. Perfect!